# Want to link to a USB Host via my laptop

Tags: usb, usb-device

I have this device that has to be setup as a USB Host.  Normally, my laptop is a USB Host, how do I connect to such a device?

When I plug the USB cable into my laptop, I don't see a `tty` being assigned (`ttyUSB0`/`ttyACM0`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a computer act as a virtual USB device for other equipments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120368/make-a-computer-act-as-a-virtual-usb-device-for-other-equipments). In particular, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283147/97255).